# Como mudar o encode no Java?

Tags: java

Estou consumindo a API do IBGE para pegar os municípios por estado. Quando imprimo os municípios os acentos ficam errados. O que eu posso fazer para arrumar isso? Abaixo o código que pega o nome dos municípios.

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
List municipios = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        municipios.add(jsonobject.getString("nome").);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que você pode fazer isso na hora de adicionar o texto à lista:

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
List municipios = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    municipios.add(new String(jsonobject.getString("nome").getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
}
```

Pegando os *bytes* da palavra e criando uma *string* em formato `UTF-8`, os acentos e caracteres serão exibidos.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado, cara!